# how to send shortcut to public desktop, with vbs

Tags: windows, shortcuts, vbscript

following the instructions of [ss64](https://ss64.com/vb/shortcut.html) I have created a vbs to create a shortcut

my `test.vbs`

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Set lnk = objShell.CreateShortcut("%HOMEDRIVE%\Users\Public\Desktop\test.lnk")
   
   lnk.TargetPath = "%HOMEDRIVE%\test\start.bat"
   lnk.Arguments = ""
   lnk.Description = "test"
   lnk.HotKey = "ALT+CTRL+F"
   lnk.IconLocation = "%HOMEDRIVE%\test\test.ico, 0"
   lnk.WindowStyle = "1"
   lnk.WorkingDirectory = "%HOMEDRIVE%\test\"
   lnk.Save
   'Clean up 
   Set lnk = Nothing
```

out

```
Error: Could not save shortcut
"c:\test\%HOMEDRIVE%\Users\Public\Desktop\test.ink"
```

If I change the path of the shortcut from `"%HOMEDRIVE%\Users\Public\Desktop\test.lnk"` to only `test.ink` the shortcut is successfully created inside the `test` folder

how can i create the shortcut in the path `"%HOMEDRIVE%\Users\Public\Desktop\test.lnk"`?

Comment: It also takes elevated permissions to write to that folder.  The error suggests your user did not launch the script with elevated permissions

Comment: solved. thanks for help

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: @DavidPostill ok sorry. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. this is the correct vbs code

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strDesktop = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
Set objShortcut = objShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\test.lnk")
objShortcut.TargetPath = "%HOMEDRIVE%\test\start.bat"
objShortcut.Description = "Start test"
objShortcut.WorkingDirectory = strDesktop
objShortcut.IconLocation = "%HOMEDRIVE%\test\test.ico, 0"
objShortcut.Save
```

Source: [social.technet.microsoft.com](http://lhttps://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/7f6fdb60-1713-4fb7-82a0-6d77a5588da2/script-to-create-a-shortcut-on-desktop-for-an-application-and-apply-a-custom-icon-to-it?forum=ITCG)